# Docker External File Access Not in /Users/ on OSX

Tags: docker, boot2docker

So, despite [Docker 1.3 now allowing easy access to external storage on OSX through boot2docker for files in /Users/](http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/), I still need to access files not in /Users/. I have a settings file in /etc/settings/ that I'd like my container to have access to. Also, the CMD in my container writes logs to /var/log in the container, which I'd rather have it write to /var/log on the host. I've been playing around with `VOLUME` and passing stuff in with `-v` at run, but I'm not getting anywhere. Googling hasn't been much help. Can someone who has this working provide help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As boot2docker now [includes VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#user-content-folder-sharing), you can now share folders on the host computer (OSX) with guest operating systems (boot2docker-vm). /Users/ is automatically mounted but you can mount/share custom folders. In your host console (OSX) :

```
 $ vboxmanage sharedfolder add "boot2docker-vm" --name settings-share --hostpath  /etc/settings --automount
```

Start boot2docker and ssh into it (`$boot2docker up` / `$boot2docker ssh`).
Choose where you want to mount the "settings-share" (/etc/settings) in the boot2docker VM :

```
$ sudo mkdir /settings-share-on-guest
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf settings-share /settings-share-on-guest
```

According that `/settings` is the volume declared in the docker container add `-v /settings-share-on-guest:/settings` to the docker run command to [mount the host directory settings-share-on-guest as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).

Works on Windows, not tested on OSX but should work.

Comment: Why do you have to supply the uid and gid?

Comment: I needed to mount two things, and one would overwrite the other when I specified gid and uid. When I switched to just `sudo mount -t vboxsf settings-share /settings-share-on-guest` everything worked. Awesome answer anyway though!

Comment: Answer edited as gid and uid are not mandatory. I don't know why it overwrites your first mount.

Comment: On `OSX` the share can be created using Virtualbox Manager tool aswell - here you can set it to automount