# Docker volume not mounting in the Ubuntu container from Windows host

Tags: windows, docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to play with Facebook's HHVM on my lovely Windows, but since it isn't supported yet I'm trying Docker.

Pretty simple. I have only these two files on the same directory in path `/c/apache/htdocs/hello-hhvm`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:wily

RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
RUN add-apt-repository "deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install hhvm

VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app
```

**hello.php**

```
<?hh echo 'its me';
```

Then I build the image:

`docker build -t hhvm .`

And run the container trying to mount the volume `/app`:

`docker run --rm -it -v /c/apache/htdocs/hello-hhvm:/app hhvm bash`

I successfully start a bash session on the container already in the `/app` directory BUUUUT there is no `hello.php` neither Dockerfile in there.

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Thanks.

Comment: For docker toolbox, you can only mount folders inside your /c/Users/name folder

Comment: does the test docker hello-world container run ok?

Comment: Thanks @warmoverflow  worked moving to my home directory. There is no way to use any path I want to?

Comment: It is possible, but involves extra steps. Basically you need to mount the Windows folder to the Docker Toolbox VM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006643/docker-external-file-access-not-in-users-on-osx

Comment: You may be interested in https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/, which resolves a lot of issues w.r.t. mounting volumes from the host.